# How to know if the iOS App you build is for 64 bit.

Tags: ios, 64-bit, executable

I am trying to build an iOS Application for 64 bit. How do I know weather it is build for 32 bit or 64 bit ?

Does Mach-O-View can help ? if Yes, where to look for it ?
Also is there any command line for it. ?

I reffered this but it does not help me to know weather this it is built or not for 64 bit. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#ifdef __LP64__
// NSLog(@"64");
#else
// NSLog(@"32");
#endif
```

It works for OS X, but I didn't test it for iOS (I don't have an iPhone5S :( ).

**Edit:**

By the way, it works fine on iPhone Simulator.

[image]

Comment: #ifdef  is a preprocessor directives take a look at it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682400/objective-c-if-syntax

Comment: thanks for the help, I tried various ways but this helped me. It helped me in working out.